# Randomize String list with animation

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to randomize to get a string in a list, and show them in a field with fade in-out animation. When i'm randomizing them, its fine. But i cant integrate that into AnimatedOpacity or any other Animation item.

```
Timer? timer;
List<String> numberList = ["1111", "2222", "3333", "4444", "5555", "6666", "7777", "8888", "9999", "1000"];
  String _current = "";

  void _shuffle() {
    String item = "";

    if (numberList.isNotEmpty) {
      numberList.shuffle();
      item = numberList.removeLast();
      setState(() {
        _current = item;
      });
      print(item);
    }
  }

  Widget testFieldText() {
    return Text(
      _current,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]),
    );
  }
```

in InitState method i've added periodicTimer for shuffling.

```
timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 4), (Timer t) => _shuffle());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to animate the change of widget. To animate between two different widget you can use `AnimatedSwitcher`. The remaining issue is that it won't work be default because you always use the same widget: `Text`. Fortunately to indicate that a widget changed you can change its `key` value. Here you simply have to use a `ValueKey` with `_current` as value to ensure the animation (it won't animate if you have the same value twice in a row though, but I guess you don't want that).

Here is a simple example from what you shared:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Timer? timer;
  List<String> numberList = [
    "1111",
    "2222",
    "3333",
    "4444",
    "5555",
    "6666",
    "7777",
    "8888",
    "9999",
    "1000"
  ];
  String _current = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 4), (Timer t) => _shuffle());
    super.initState();
  }

  void _shuffle() {
    String item = "";

    if (numberList.isNotEmpty) {
      numberList.shuffle();
      item = numberList.removeLast();
      setState(() {
        _current = item;
      });
      print(item);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        child: Text(
          _current,
          key: ValueKey(_current),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```